# Can array indexes be named in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

I'm wondering if the index of an array can be given a name in C# instead of the default index value. What I'm basically looking for is the C# equivalent of the following PHP code:

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "some foo value",
    "bar" => "some bar value",
);
```

Cheers.

Comment: You're really wanting a hash.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

PHP blends the concept of arrays and the concept of dictionaries (aka hash tables, hash maps, associative arrays) into a single [`array` type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

In .NET and most other programming environments, arrays are always indexed numerically. For named indices, use a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) instead:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "foo", "some foo value" }, 
    { "bar", "some bar value" }
};
```

Unlike PHP's associative arrays, dictionaries in .NET are not sorted. If you need a sorted dictionary (but you probably don't), .NET provides a [sorted dictionary type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

In an array, no. However, there is the very useful `Dictionary` class, which is a collection of `KeyValuePair` objects. It's similar to an array in that it is an iterable collection of objects with keys, but more general in that the key can be any type.

Example:

```
Dictionary<string, int> HeightInInches = new Dictionary<string, int>();
HeightInInches.Add("Joe", 72);
HeightInInches.Add("Elaine", 60);
HeightInInches.Add("Michael", 59);

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> person in HeightInInches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person.Key + " is " + person.Value + " inches tall.");
}
```

[MSDN Documentation for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) in C#. This is the data structure that does what you want in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Dictionary<string, FooValue>` or similar type or collection type or, if you must stick to array, define an `Enum` with your labels.